# Unable to import pandas in Replit.com

Tags: python, pandas

`import pandas`

So I am working on a python project and want to import pandas library on **[https://replit.com/~](https://replit.com/%7E)**

For some reasons, it shows some attribute error when I run the project.

Does anyone know ho do I fix or manually install pandas on replit?
Attaching Screenshot of an error herewith.
[image: The attribute error that I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually packages have a lot of errors in replit but you can try this: -

Pandas does actually work on repl.it - you have to install it from the package manager. To do so, click the cube on the side navigation bar and type pandas into the search box. Then click on the pandas search entry and hit the plus sign. Tell me if this works!

[image]

Or

Broken package installs can usually be fixed by,

Updating pip and installing pandas from PyPI. By default, Repl.it comes with pip version 19.3.1, but the latest available version for python 3.8 is pip-21.1.1.

```
~/repl$ pip -V
pip 19.3.1 from /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
~/repl$ pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.2)
Collecting pytz>=2017.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/94/784178ca5dd892a98f113cdd923372024dc04b8d40abe77ca76b5fb90ca6/pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
Installing collected packages: pytz, pandas
Successfully installed pandas-1.2.4 pytz-2021.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Pandas does not work on replit at all, because a lot of modules, which Pandas needs to work properly, do not work in replit. An online Compiler is also not the best choice for doing dataprocessing, it would be better if you install an Interpreter for python on your PC.