# NLTK is not importing into my program properly

Tags: python, nltk

[image]

Why can’t I import nltk?

I don’t know what to do or who to ask. I’ve tried everything I know of, but I can’t know a lot, so I’m asking for help here. It would be nice if you could help me. Ignore the rest of the program, and only focus on the first few lines. That’s where the error is.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you run `pip install nltk` with your virtual environemnt activated?

Comment: It's also helpful to post "everything" you've tried, so we don't go through all possible solutions.  Have you installed `nltk` with `pip install nltk`?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575510/unable-to-import-pandas-in-replit-com. Same problem with `pandas` but probably it is the same with `nltk`.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76430808/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`pip install nltk --user`

If you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable,

`python -m pip install nltk`